# Hash functions in Bitcoin source codes

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm new to programming. I got into it because I wanted to learn Bitcoin.

I've downloaded the source files from Bitcoin Core. Can anyone enlighten me where the source codes related to the hash functions are located at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say in the src/crypto folder: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/efb4383ef6c69e801ddca160a53e7fb4ee8b156a/src/crypto